# Как сделать if else с ячейкой Excel?

Tags: python

Допустим если в ячейке B2 значение = 1, то записать в ячейку C2 значение = 2.

Работаю через openpyxl.

Знаю как сделать это в txt файле:

```
findtext = open('File.txt', w) 
word = 'Some text'

if word in findtext.read():    
   findtext.write('Example')    
   findtext.close()
```

Вот что-то вроде такой конструкции нужно сделать в Excel файле. Как записать слово в ячейку знаю, а вот как сделать проверку есть ли слово в ячейке не знаю, прошу помочь.

Comment: *Как записать слово в ячейку знаю, а вот как сделать проверку есть ли слово в ячейке не знаю, прошу помочь.* Что именно не знаешь? как прочитать? странно, записывать умеешь, читать нет... или не знаешь как сравнить прочитанное с нужным значением?

Comment: Не знаю как сравнить да, как это будет выглядить при использовании openpyxl

Comment: Да обычный `IF`: `if (wb["B2"] == 1): wb["C2"] = 2`. Ничего экзотического.

Comment: Увидел теперь) Спасибо! Сейчас попробую